# Combining histograms with a density plot in R

Tags: r, histogram

It seems that I have a problem of scaling between histograms and density lines when I combine both in one plot. There is a clear visual difference between the density curve plotting alone and the combination of the two. What is the solution to have the same shape and scale between the two plots (density alone and density when combining it with histo)? I use this code:

```
hist(dataList[[cl12]],xlim=range(minx,maxx),breaks=seq(minx,maxx,pasx),col="grey",main=paste(paramlab,"Group",groupnum,Cl,sep=" "),xlab="",freq=FALSE) 
d<-density(dataList[[cl12]])
lines(d,col="red")
```

With

```
  dataList[[cl12]] <- c(4.399449e-02,  2.161474e-02, -1.515223e-05,  1.298059e+01,
      3.163949e-01, -1.785220e+00,  1.041053e+01,  6.327219e-01, -5.778590e-03)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look at `ggplot2`: The histogram plot there can be easily combined with a (properly scaled) density curve, search for "geom_density" in the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_histogram.html)

Comment: This question would have been easier to answer if you had stripped out the various unnecessary variables like minx, maxx, paramlab, groupnum etc and made it a reproducible example by eg using "x" instead of "dataList[[c12]]".

Answer (score 3):

By default hist plots bin frequencies.  If you want to display the bin probabilites, so that it matches the scale of a density plot, you can use hist's freq parameter.  Here's an example:

```
x = rnorm(1000)
plot(density(x))
hist(x, freq=F, add=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing the same thing.

```
test <- rnorm(1000)
plot(density(test))
par(new=T)
hist(test, freq=F, xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="")
```

Comment: This is what I already do. Look at my code. This does not answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you do have a problem other than the very small number of data points.  When I change your code to a reproducible version it seems fine.  eg

```
x <- c(4.399449e-02,  2.161474e-02, -1.515223e-05,  1.298059e+01,
      3.163949e-01, -1.785220e+00,  1.041053e+01,  6.327219e-01, -5.778590e-03)

hist(x,col="grey",freq=FALSE, breaks=10) 
d<-density(x)
lines(d,col="red")
```

This gives an ugly plot but obviously this is because of the small number of data points:

[image]

If you do the same approach with more data points it seems fine eg:

```
x <- rgamma(100,1,1)
```

(same graphing code used)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Peter. However, I realise that I should have been more specific. In fact, what I try to get is a plot with two figures, one above the other (par(mfrow=c(2, 1)), with a combination between a histogram and a density curve of two samples of different length. Important: I would like both have the same x-axis and the histograms (freq=false) have the same bin widths. I can't do it. Density curves seem unrealistic (They rise much higher than the bars!). How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that really does not come across as what your question is asking.  I suggest you start again with a fresh question with a reproducible example using simulated data.